# configure internal and external ip addresses on ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, networking

At the moment I have a host windows server, inside VM's are installed.
One VM is an Ubuntu 16.04 server, which has only external IP and accessible only through internet.

I have added second network interface for this Ubuntu server.
Now how to configure internal IP for these Ubuntu server, in order to access with internal IP if i am connected to LAN?

The eth0 has an external IP and is working fine.

When I add static internal IP to eth1 and restart the network with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

the following error appears:

[Network restart error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqRtj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to give a new configuration for that interface:

```
ifconfig -a
```

will give you the full list of interfaces. Then, check the MAC address to see which one is connected to your LAN network.
Open the configuration file

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add the needed configuration for your interface. It will look something like this:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.0.2.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.0.2.1
dns-nameservers 192.0.2.101
```

**Code explanation**
*eth1*: would be your internal interface. This will deppend on your set up, it could be anything else.
*auto*: makes the interface wake when starting the server.
*iface eth1 inet static*: the interface takes a static configuration, change *static* to *dhcp* otherwise. If changed to *dhcp*, everything below that line is not needed.
Note that not all the options are needed in order to configurate the interface.